# How can I protect a painted floor?

Tags: paint, floor

I want to paint my stairs, but I can't find "floor paint" in suitable colours.

Can I use another kind of paint, and then give it a protective coating?

What kinds of paint/protection would be compatible?

Comment: A hardwre store or paint store should be able to mix whatever color you like starting from white (or "base") floor paint.

Comment: If these are exterior concrete steps you are just creating a maintenance issue since the paint will flake off over the years. What kind of stairs are these?

Comment: Interior wooden steps.

Answer (score 2):

You can get [floor paint](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Valspar-Base-2-Tintable-Satin-Latex-Base-2-Porch-and-Floor-Paint-Actual-Net-Contents-31-fl-oz/3087057) in a tintable base and have it tinted to the color of your choice.

[Rust-oleum](https://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/concrete-and-garage-floor-paint/concrete-and-garage-floor-paint-tint-base/) has an option as well.

[Sherwin Williams](https://www.sherwin-williams.com/homeowners/products/porch-floor-enamel) has an option as well.

Comment: I only need small amounts of multiple colours, so mixing at a hardware store isn't economical.